# Equivalent of 'IN' or 'NOT' operator in sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I have a sqoop job torun, The conditions includes :

```
WHERE cond1='' AND date = '2-12-xxxx' AND date = '3-12-xxxx' AND date = '3-12-xxxx'.
```

Is there a IN conditional in sqoop similar to sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `sqoop import` using `--query` and pass any query to get the data.

In `--where` you have to pass conditions like this --where `"cond1='value' and cond2 in (<comma seperated values>)"`.

If you use where condition on table, it will apply like this `select * from <table> where <condition specified in where clause>` to fetch the data and hence you can pass any valid conditions in where.